# Bash error every time Terminal is Opened

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm on Mac OSX 10.8.5. I have rails and RVM set up. Every time terminal is opened, I am greeted with this error:

```
-bash: /Users/Justin/.bash_profile: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /Users/Justin/.bash_profile: line 2: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:(...)'
```

Here's what's inside `.bash_profile`:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:(...)
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

I'm quite new to Rails. Although this error message doesn't appear to be interrupting anything, it is quite annoying. How would I go about editing my `.bash_profile` to stop this error message?

Comment: You've removed the line that is causing problems. Not sure how you're hoping anyone can help. Also, this probably belongs on super user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:(...)
```

to

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

this will prepend `/usr/local/bin` to your `PATH` variable which is probably what you want.